# Redirect non-existent https domain to different url

Tags: redirect, https, dns, google-index

I have what appears to be a unique situation. I recently developed a site where the previous site was as http://example.com. They also had example.com that redirected to domain.com. In the new site, they wanted it to resolve to holiday-heroes.org and have holidayheroesfoundation.org redirect to the new site.

Long story short, new site is setup at example.com and http://example.com is redirecting properly. However, Google has index http**s**://example.com for some reason and I've recently learned that you can't redirect a secure domain. Furthermore, there's no hosting associated with the old domain anymore so I can't put an .htaccess file there to redirect. To my knowledge, they never had a certificate on the domain at all.

My question is, how do I either get http**s**:/example.com to redirect to example.com or how to do I get google to remove the incorrect domain entirely from its index?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Of course you can redirect secure site (for example `https://google.com/` will redirect you to `https://www.google.com/`)

Comment: I'm trying to go from https to http and it's not a secure site, it's just a bad url from google. The site has never been secure

Comment: I understand. In order to redirect from `https://example.com` to anywhere, you need to have a (active) site that is responding to `https://example.com`, which implies that you need SSL cert for example.com domain. The site does not need any content, it just need to respond with `301` along with the new location

Comment: Ok, so you're saying If I purchase the certificate then I can do the redirect? Because currently I don't have have that.

Comment: Yes. And there are free certs these days (https://www.startssl.com/Support?v=1, https://letsencrypt.org/) so you can try

Comment: The hosting company that holds the domain says that there's no way to do the redirect without moving the hosting back to them. That might just be them trying to get more business, but regardless I'm hoping I can just get google to stop indexing the https:// url and that will solve the issue - Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wait. If it is your domain, no hosting company can 'hold' it. Still, if you want them to do the redirect, you usually do have to arrange hosting with them. But if you already pay for hosting the holiday-heroes.org, you should be able to configure that hosting to do that redirect also. So: 1) configure your current hosting to serve both `holiday-heroes.org` and `holidayheroesfoundation.org`, and `http` and `https` for both domains 2) Configure it so that if the request is for `holidayheroesfoundation.org`, just reply with redirect to `holiday-heroes.org` (this is one simple .htaccess rule)

Comment: o now we're on to something. Ok, i've transferred the domain to where my hosting is and created a new directory with an .htaccess file in it. I know need to tell both the https:// and the http:// to both redirect to the new domain. I thought I would be able to google this and find it but i can only find either redirecting https:// to same http:// or just redirecting http:// to a new domain. Any advice? thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
# Rewrite holidayheroesfoundation.org => https://holiday-heroes.org

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.holidayheroesfoundation\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://holiday-heroes.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```